# Whats the class type for a Non-Stored Password Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to kick off a job from another and need the `$class` for a non-stored password parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/PasswordParameterValue.java) is the class that holds password values. So it should be `PasswordParameterValue`